# Create SharePoint 2013 web part that loads user controls

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, user-controls, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I need to create a web part that loads users controls into it.
All the answers I found are either outdated or not working.

I'm using visual studio 2015 and SharePoint 2013.
I created a project with my user control and other with the web part, but I don't know how to link them...

Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your webpart is not a Visual webpart, you can load user controls like this (in the webpart cs file):

```
namespace ProjectName.Folder.Custom_Webpart
{
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public class Custom_Webpart : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart
    {
        private const string _ascxPath = @"~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/15/ProjectName/Folder/Custom_UserControl.ascx";

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            var control = Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath) as Custom_UserControl;
            //this.ChromeType = PartChromeType.None;
            Controls.Add(control);
        }
    }
}
```

If your webpart is a Visual webpart, you can load user controls inserting the following instructions in your webpart .ascx file:

```
<%@ Register Src="/_controltemplates/15/ProjectName/Folder/Custom_UserControl.ascx" TagPrefix="Custom" TagName="CustomControl" %>

<Custom:CustomControl runat="server" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try that.

Comment: Do I need to deploy the user control project in any specific location?

Comment: Custom user controls should be deployed to a SharePoint mapped folder (CONTROLTEMPLATES). Take a look here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vssharepointtoolsblog/2010/03/12/deploying-files-using-mapped-folders/

Comment: Hello. I created a mapped folder (to controltemplates) in my sharepoint webpart project.
Now, do I add an existing item (the user control) to that folder? Or is there another way? thanks

Comment: just drag & drop the user control  (on Visual Studio) into the mapped folder (and change the control registration src/path). Take a look here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231577(v=vs.120).aspx or here. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-custom-user-control-templates-in-sharepoint-2013-using-visual-studio/

Comment: Hello, thanks again
so, basically, i have to develop the user controls inside the sharepoint project. I had the impression I could do it in an external project.

Comment: Yes, you have to use a SharePoint project for your custom user controls. Was my answer useful?

Comment: Yes.thank you. Now I have to figure out how to use a web.config in this SharePoint project...

Comment: It depends on what you have to do with the configuration values. For connection strings you can use the Secure Store Service. For simple values you can user Property bags... Open a new question explaining what you have to do.